# React High Order Components Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compiler-errors, components

I got this error in React 17.0.2 when trying to implement a high order component (HOC):

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I searched the error online and couldn't find any guidance as to what could be generating it. Here is a simplified code that reproduces the error:
index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import './index.css'

import App from './components/App'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

index.css

`body { background-color: aquamarine; }`

withPointlessHOC.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function withPointlessHOC(component) {
    const Component = component
    return (
        <div>
            <Component />
        </div>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'

import withPointlessHOC from './withPointlessHOC'

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello
        </div>
    )
}

const PointlessHOC = withPointlessHOC(App)
export default PointlessHOC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had forgotten to return a function and was attempting to render as normal. In HOC you must return a function that contains the render instructions. Once I corrected this by adding the return into withPointlessHOC like below:

import React from 'react'

// A High Order Component or HOC is a function that takes a component as its first argument and returns a new component that wraps the given component, providing extra capabilities to it.

```
export default function withPointlessHOC(component) {
    const Component = component
    return function(props) {
        return (
            <div>
                <Component />
            </div>
        )
    }
    
}
```

voila, the error went away. To make it complete (pointless, except for understanding the error), I spread the props inside the  using:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function withPointlessHOC(component) {
    const Component = component
    return function(props) {
        return (
            <div>
                <Component {...props}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
}
```